# Como criar Function no Banco com Migrations ef core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, asp-net-core

Eu criei uma function em Postgresql e gostaria que ela fosse gerada junto com o banco de dados na migration inicial.

Tentei da seguinte maneira e nao tive resultados

```cs
 protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
 {
            Database.GetDbConnection().CreateCommand().CommandText = "função vai aqui";
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use o add-migration e [personalize a migração](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/#empty-migrations).

> Às vezes, é útil adicionar uma migração sem fazer alterações no
>   modelo. Nesse caso, adicionar uma nova migração cria arquivos de
>   código com classes vazias. Você pode personalizar essa migração para
>   executar operações que não se relacionam diretamente ao modelo do EF
>   Core.

Exemplo de `migration` personalizada:

```
public partial class MinhaFuncao : Migration
{
    protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        var function = @"
                    CREATE FUNCTION MINHAFUNCAO(@ST VARCHAR(1000))
                    RETURNS VARCHAR(1000)
                    BEGIN
                       RETURN('Minha função')
                    END
                ";

        migrationBuilder.Sql(function);
    }

    protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Olá George,

Eu fiz assim:    




 public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
    {
       protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
       {
            Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(" sql script da função aqui");
       }
   }





Acha valido?

Comment: @iagosoares é válido sim, pode até por como resposta, seria mais uma opção :)

Comment: Obrigado George!
Desculpe a formatação da resposta, estou aprendendo ainda rsrs

Answer (score 1):

Uma outra opção encontrada

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
   {
       protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("sql script vai aqui");
        }
   }
```